# Moving an existing windows8 installation onto raid

Tags: windows-8, boot, raid

I've tried moving my current windows installation onto a raid0 array and I've run into issues I'm guessing have to do with drivers for the raid not being installed.

I used gParted and dd to: backup entire drive, set up raid0 and then restore onto the array.

Windows starts booting but then crashes halfway through and reboots me into recovery mode. Recovery doesn't really help me and safe mode doesn't seem to work at all. (Nothing happens after windows logo pops up)

Is there a way to actually see what's going on instead of that annoying logo?

Are there any other ways I can figure out what is wrong before I give up and start over?

Comment: When you do decide to start over, just use Windows' internal image backup system, it should allow/enable you to restore to dissimilar hardware.

Comment: Went with that option now. Seemed like a more reasonable approach. Hopefully the dd backup will work fine with a single disk.

Comment: install the drivers for the RAID, then duplicate the disk, restore the disk to the RAID, then boot to the RAID.

Comment: It seems it's not possible due to running into catch-22. To install drivers I need to have the software raid active. I've tried the solution posted across the web telling me to set a register key but it doesn't seem to work at all in my case.

Comment: I have installed hardware based RAID drivers without the sotware raid being setup before.  The suggestion about using the correct procedure to backup your system is a better suggestion anyways.

Comment: I assume I still need to install the drivers before the backup. Which is where I get stuck at.

Comment: Ah and of course windows can't restore from dynamic disks.. That is it can't find them unless you have an active windows installation. Aka backup works when you don't need it.

Comment: Installer Windows,moved files to basic disk. The recovery tool refuses to restore to the disks when they are set up in raid though. Complaining about disks missing and uuniqueids